# convert coordinate(x,y) to a single point and draw a rectangle on image

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an api that returns me 4 points in form of coordinates(x,y) and confidence to find out how much they are closure to actual ones . by using these coordinates I have to draw a rectangle, I have a function it takes for points in form of object like

```
({"x": 36,"y": 137,"width": 119,"height": 181})
```

and draw a rectangle for me.

my problem is how to convert api coordinates to appropriate object format.
api response is

```
            "confidence": 0.684831,
            "coords": [
                {
                    "x": 0.17787032,
                    "y": 0.16400336
                },
                {
                    "x": 0.39262342,
                    "y": 0.16400336
                },
                {
                    "x": 0.39262342,
                    "y": 0.17325483
                },
                {
                    "x": 0.17787032,
                    "y": 0.17325483
                }
            ]
```

how to convert these point in the form cordinates to (x, y, width, height)

Comment: Simple math to get width and height. Subtract the x/y from the 1st and 3rd coords

Comment: Use things like Object.keys, Array.map, Array.forEach, etc. All common methods to transform one data format to another

Comment: @JeremyThille thanks for response . but the thing is i know how to do these thing the only question is how to convert coordinates to points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I solved this by making this formula first I get the 4 points and then the height and width

```
let startX = Math.round(myImageWidth * coords[0].x);
let startY = Math.round(myImageHeight * coords[0].y);
let endX = Math.round(myImageWidth * coords[2].x);
let endY = Math.round(myImageHeight * coords[2].y);

let width = endX - startX;
let height = endY - startY;
```